# Present UIAlertView from current modal's delegate

Tags: swift, delegates, uialertview, modalviewcontroller

The issue in question involves an `AddItemView` which is presented modally by its delegate and contains a tableView. When the user selects an item from the tableView, it triggers an action on the delegate. Depending on the response from the server, the delegate may present a either another modal view or a UIAlertView on top of the current modal.

**Important Note:** This UIAlertView needs to be presented while the modal is still on screen. The modally presented view containing the tableView cannot be dismissed after user selection because the user needs to be able to select multiple items from the table and, one by one, send them back to the delegate for processing.

Currently, the UIAlerView is not being displayed and I suspect it is because the already-presented modal is preventing that. Is there a workaround to present the UIAlertView from the delegate when the delegate is sitting underneath a modal and without dismissing that modal?

The UIAlertView is currently displayed like so by the delegate, while the delegate is sitting under a modal:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Error message from server", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "actionOne", style: .Default, handler: { action in
    // perform some action

    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "actionTwo", style: .Destructive, handler: { action in
    // perform some action

    }))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here is the error that is returned when the UIAlertView is presented by the delegate:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x156da6300> on <productionLINK_Scanner.ContainerContents: 0x156e65b20> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

If possible, please provide answer using Swift.

Comment: Where exactly in the controller lifetime do you attempt to present the alert controller? There is no problem to present a controller on top of another. Also, you do not need to dismiss the alert controller in your handlers, it is dismissed automatically.

Comment: @LeoNatan The UIAlertView is presented from the delegate when a users selects a row in the presented modal's tableView. It is important to note that the modally-presented tableView (it's actually a tableView embedded in a UIView ) needs to stay on the screen - it cannot be dismissed as the user needs to be able to select multiple items from the table and send each back to the delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**:

Used the following extension, thanks to [yonat](https://gist.github.com/yonat) on GitHub:

```
extension UIApplication {

    class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(base: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(base: presented)
        }
        return base
    }
}
```

Within the delegate in question, it was implemented like so:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Title", message: "Message Body", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { action in

}))

if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController(base: self) {
    topController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

} else {
    // If all else fails, attempt to present the alert from this controller.
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

This now allows the following process:

1. `ContainerView` is loaded as a delegate of `ItemTableView`
2. User clicks `searchButton`
3. `ContainerView` modally presents a list of items `ItemTableView`
4. Each time a use selects a row in `ItemTableView`, the `didSelectItem` function is called in the instance of `ContainerView` that presented the `ItemTableView`. The `ItemTableView` does NOT get dismissed - the user can continue selecting items.
5. `ContainerView` submits a request to the server
6. Depending on the response, the `ContainerView` may present a `UIAlertView`.
7. The `alertView` is properly displayed using the above-mention code on top of whatever view is top-most in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

"When the user selects an item, it triggers and action on the delegate"

set a break point at start of the delegate method which is triggered by selecting an item. check whether that delegate method is being called or not ?

and test this too. `(ACTION :UIAlertAction!)in`